# VirtualBox: Guru Meditation -363 (VERR_SEM_DESTROYED)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

- Host: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
- Guest: Windows 8.1
- VirtualBox: 4.3.10_Ubuntur93012

For some reasons, `apt-get dist-upgrade` just bump my version from 4.3.10 to 4.3.34 and I got this error when using `vboxheadless`:

```
virtualbox@vbox-1:~$ vboxheadless -h
VBoxHeadless: Error -1912 in supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime!
VBoxHeadless: RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912

VBoxHeadless: Tip! It may help to reinstall VirtualBox.
```

Found this from `dmesg`:

```
SUP_IOCTL_COOKIE: Version mismatch. Requested: 0x1a000b  Min: 0x1a000b  Current: 0x1a0007
```

So, I have to downgraded to 4.3.10:

```
dpkg -l | grep virtualbox
hi  virtualbox                          4.3.10-dfsg-1                           amd64        x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
hi  virtualbox-dkms                     4.3.10-dfsg-1                           all          x86 virtualization solution - kernel module sources for dkms
hi  virtualbox-source                   4.3.10-dfsg-1                           all          x86 virtualization solution - kernel module source
```

I would like to  create a new VM by cloning an existing Windows 8.1 VM but I got the below error when starting:

```
00:00:02.941640 Guest Log: BIOS: Boot : bseqnr=1, bootseq=0231
00:00:02.941769 Guest Log: BIOS: Boot from Floppy 0 failed
00:00:02.941914 Guest Log: BIOS: Boot : bseqnr=2, bootseq=0023
00:00:02.942052 Guest Log: BIOS: CDROM boot failure code : 0002
00:00:02.942151 Guest Log: BIOS: Boot from CD-ROM failed
00:00:02.942278 Guest Log: BIOS: Boot : bseqnr=3, bootseq=0002
00:00:02.970936 Guest Log: BIOS: Booting from Hard Disk...
00:00:03.398751 Display::handleDisplayResize(): uScreenId = 0, pvVRAM=00007f1158000000 w=1024 h=768 bpp=24 cbLine=0xC00, flags=0x1
00:00:03.440094 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
00:00:03.440095 !!
00:00:03.440095 !!                 Guru Meditation -363 (VERR_SEM_DESTROYED)
00:00:03.440102 !!
00:00:03.440141 !!
00:00:03.440141 !! {mappings, <NULL>}
00:00:03.440142 !!
00:00:03.440153
00:00:03.440153 The mappings are DISABLED.

...

00:00:03.464693 VGA Sequencer (3C5): SR index 3C4:04
00:00:03.464697  SR00:03 SR01:00 SR02:0F SR03:00 SR04:0A
00:00:03.464723 !!
00:00:03.464723 !! {vgatext}
00:00:03.464723 !!
00:00:03.464727 Not in text mode!
00:00:03.464729 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
00:00:03.464745 emR3Debug: rc=VERR_SEM_DESTROYED
00:00:04.465588 Changing the VM state from 'RUNNING' to 'GURU_MEDITATION'.
```

Full VBox.log: https://gist.github.com/quantonganh/47cab2028cd034e545c5

Comment: Did you turn it off and on again?

Comment: Do you mean restart VirtualBox? If so, no, because I have some running VMs.

Comment: No, I mean restart the computer. You will have to unload and reload all of VirtualBox's kernel modules, which have changed with the upgrade.

Comment: I cannot restart now. The problem is the old kernel modules were loaded long time ago. After downgraded, it's running the version that match with virtualbox's version. Is there any other way that can bring it back without restarting?